# How can I mount my router to my table?

Tags: hardware, routers

Some time ago, I bought a second-hand table saw.  The original owner had extended the table with a section where he mounted a router.  The holes are in the pattern of a [Group C router](http://go.rockler.com/tech/Group_C_Routers.pdf) and I recently bought a Porter-Cable 7518 which should fit.  The holes line up but the screws holding the sub-base on the router base are 5/16"-18 and have a head about a 1/2" across.  The countersink holes in the table are much smaller.  Are 5/16" machine screws available with smaller heads?  It doesn't seem that a reducer (a 5/16"-18 outside thread and something smaller inside) would work well here, if such a thing is even available.  I could get smaller machine screws which would fit inside the threads in the base and then put a nut below but that would certainly make mounting and unmounting a chore.  I could get a larger countersink bit and make the holes fit the larger heads but that seems hard to get right.  Any thoughts?

[image: Router table]
[image: Closeup of hole and screw]

Comment: Are the holes in the table possibly counterbored for cap-head screws rather than countersunk for flathead screws? Or just increase the size of the countersink...

Comment: No, the holes in the router table are conical pits, not cylinders.

Comment: A larger diameter counter sink bit and or possibly one with a shallow taper. You do want the heads to be flush or slightly below the table top. not really that difficult. counter sink just a little at a time checking to see if the heads will sit flush. This can be done with a hand drill.